# Nested XSL Increment Variable

Tags: xslt, increment

I have the following code:

```
<xsl:for-each select"/*/cities/city">
    <xsl:for-each select="./items/item">
         <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What i want to do is make a global counter that accounts for both the global scope and the inner scope. So, if for example:

The first iteration of the inner loop has 7 items, the count would be `7`. When it performs the second iteration, the new count should be `7 + position()`.

How Do I accomplish something like that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post an example of the input (with at least two occurrences of `city`) and the expected output - see [mcve].

Comment: It's a good idea to force yourself to avoid time-oriented words ("when it performs") when discussing XSLT. They reveal that you are thinking procedurally, as if an XSLT stylesheet was a sequence of steps performed in order. You need to think in terms of describing your output as a function of your input. As it is, you haven't shown your input, you haven't shown your desired output, all you have shown us is code that doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing an input and the expected output. Apparently you could do simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select"/*/cities/city/items/item">
    <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

to get the specified result. If for some reason you do need to nest the two `xsl:for-each` instructions, consider using `xsl:number` to number the items.